# Read file from a directory outside of Web project

Tags: servlets, jboss, web-container

my web application project (JBoss AS) needs to read a file which resides outside of this project. For example, the file to be read is under /tmp/.

It looks like classes in the project can't access files under /tmp/. However, it can output to a file in /tmp/.

Is this normal? How to access /tmp/ directory in a Web application?

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.io.tmpdir` system property.

```
File tmpDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
//Use tmpDir to access files in tmp directory
```

Make sure there are unix permissions to read/write contents on tmp directory.